# Add a newline to a string encoded as an XML element

Tags: xml, go

Is there a way to add a new line in a specific XML Field? We are using the `\n` to insert a new line, but instead of getting a new line, it only adds 1 space. We also tried to use the `<br />` but it only adds up as part of the Description.

Code:

```golang
type Person struct {
    Name        string `xml:"name"`
    Age         int    `xml:"age"`
    City        string `xml:"city"`
    Description string `xml:"Description"`
}

func main() {
  person := &Person{
        Name: "John Doe",
        Age:  32,
        City: "New York",
    }
    ...
    someText := "some text to insert"
    // some logic here
    ...
    person.Description := fmt.Sprintf("Some description here: %v\n", someText)
    ...
    // code for generating the XML file
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Person>
  <name>John Doe</name>
  <age>32</age>
  <city>New York</city>
  <Description>some text here .... </Description>
</Person>
```

Comment: Either you're doing something not the way you explain or I do not uderstand the problem. [This](https://go.dev/play/p/JIFaa6WFBe9) simple example demonstrates that a `\n` gets sensibly and expectedly encoded as `&xA;`.

Comment: If you were expecting to get a real line break (a byte with code 0x0A) in the resulting XML document, your expectation was wrong—please see 2.10 and 2.11 of [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-white-space). Basically, that would be what is called "insignificant white space", and that can only be controlled on the level of the XML encoder not _the content_ it encodes, and as far as the Go's `encoding/xml` is concerned, you have pretty limited set of such knobs, which are all documented.